# How to inherit open files in a sub process on certain file descriptors?

Tags: haskell

I want to open some file descriptor (file, socket, pipe, whatever) and start a process for example with [createProcess](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.4.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess) so that the file descriptor opened above is available as file descriptor 3 to the sub process?

Is there a package or module, that provides such behaviour out of the box?

I know, I could do my own forking and remapping of file descriptors in the child.

Comment: Maye you could try `createProcess (proc "command" []){ std_out = UseHandle h }`, if you manage to open `h` at file descriptor 3. There should be a way to do that.

Comment: stdout is always file descriptor 1 so that doesn't help. But it shows, that there must already be some remapping of file descriptors somewhere.

Comment: The trick is opening the file on file descriptor 3 in the first place; if you do that, the child inherits the file descriptor automatically.

Comment: Roughly speaking, import `System.IO.POSIX`, then 1) use `dup` to make a copy of your current file descriptor 3, 2) use `dupTo` to copy your opened file to fd 3, 3) start the new process, then 4) use `dupTo` again to restore your saved descriptor to 3 if you did step 1.

Comment: (Shells make this easy, but I realize now that I've never cared about specific file descriptors *except* in shell.)

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I know I can do my own remapping.

Comment: You could search through reverse [dependencies of unix](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.4/package/unix-2.7.2.2/revdeps) for a packet which does it but snap clicking on words "shell" "exec" "run" did not give anything